# Need to know what's the contents of /var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist from Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, launchd, daemons

I accidentally issued the following command:

`# launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/`

I wish to see outputs of mac os x mountain lion `launchd% list` command. See below on pastie the current running services.

Here is the output from the mistake command:

```
# launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/
bind(): Address already in use
bind(): Address already in use
bind(): Address already in use
bind(): Address already in use
com.apple.ActivityMonitor: Already loaded
com.apple.afpfs_afpLoad: Already loaded
com.apple.afpfs_checkafp: Already loaded
com.apple.AirPlayXPCHelper: Already loaded
com.apple.AirPort.wps: Already loaded
com.apple.airportd: Already loaded
com.apple.airport.updateprefs: Already loaded
com.apple.alf: Already loaded
com.apple.AOSNotification-FMM: Already loaded
com.apple.appleprofilepolicyd: Already loaded
com.apple.apsd: Already loaded
com.apple.aslmanager: Already loaded
com.apple.audio.coreaudiod: Already loaded
com.apple.auditd: Already loaded
com.apple.authorizationhost: Already loaded
com.apple.autofsd: Already loaded
com.apple.automountd: Already loaded
com.apple.avbdeviced: Already loaded
com.apple.awacsd: Already loaded
com.apple.backupd: Already loaded
com.apple.blued: Already loaded
com.apple.bnepd: Already loaded
com.apple.bsd.dirhelper: Already loaded
com.apple.bsd.launchdadd: Already loaded
com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.daemon: Already loaded
com.apple.cmio.AVCAssistant: Already loaded
com.apple.cmio.IIDCVideoAssistant: Already loaded
com.apple.cmio.VDCAssistant: Already loaded
com.apple.configd: Already loaded
com.apple.CoreRAID: Already loaded
com.apple.coreservices.appleevents: Already loaded
com.apple.coreservices.appleid.passwordcheck: Already loaded
com.apple.coreservicesd: Already loaded
com.apple.corestorage.corestoraged: Already loaded
com.apple.corestorage.corestoragehelperd: Already loaded
com.apple.coresymbolicationd: Already loaded
com.apple.cvmsServ: Already loaded
com.apple.DiagnosticReportCleanUp: Already loaded
com.apple.diskarbitrationd: Already loaded
com.apple.diskmanagementd: Already loaded
com.apple.distnoted.xpc.daemon: Already loaded
com.apple.dpd: Already loaded
com.apple.dspluginhelperd: Already loaded
com.apple.DumpGPURestart: Already loaded
com.apple.DumpPanic: Already loaded
com.apple.dvdplayback.setregion: Already loaded
com.apple.dynamic_pager: Already loaded
com.apple.eapolcfg_auth: Already loaded
com.apple.efilogin-helper: Already loaded
com.apple.emond.aslmanager: Already loaded
com.apple.emond: Already loaded
com.apple.familycontrols: Already loaded
com.apple.FileCoordination: Already loaded
com.apple.findmymacd: Already loaded
com.apple.findmymacmessenger: Already loaded
com.apple.fontd: Already loaded
com.apple.fontmover: Already loaded
com.apple.FontWorker: Already loaded
com.apple.fseventsd: Already loaded
com.apple.geod: Already loaded
com.apple.gkreport: Already loaded
com.apple.gssd: Already loaded
com.apple.hdiejectd: Already loaded
com.apple.hidd: Already loaded
com.apple.IFCStart: Already loaded
com.apple.installd: Already loaded
com.apple.kcproxy: Already loaded
com.apple.Kerberos.digest-service: Already loaded
com.apple.Kerberos.kadmind: Already loaded
com.apple.Kerberos.kcm: Already loaded
com.apple.Kerberos.kdc: Already loaded
com.apple.Kerberos.kpasswdd: Already loaded
com.apple.KernelEventAgent: Already loaded
com.apple.kextd: Already loaded
com.apple.kuncd: Already loaded
com.apple.locate: Already loaded
com.apple.locationd: Already loaded
com.apple.lockd: Already loaded
com.apple.locum: Already loaded
com.apple.logind: Already loaded
com.apple.loginwindow: Already loaded
com.apple.ManagedClient: Already loaded
com.apple.mbicloudsetupd: Already loaded
com.apple.mdmclient.daemon: Already loaded
com.apple.mDNSResponder: Already loaded
com.apple.mDNSResponderHelper: Already loaded
com.apple.metadata.mds: Already loaded
com.apple.metadata.mds.scan: Already loaded
com.apple.metadata.mds.spindump: Already loaded
com.apple.msrpc.lsarpc: Already loaded
com.apple.msrpc.mdssvc: Already loaded
com.apple.msrpc.netlogon: Already loaded
com.apple.msrpc.srvsvc: Already loaded
com.apple.msrpc.wkssvc: Already loaded
com.apple.netauth.sys.auth: Already loaded
com.apple.netauth.sys.gui: Already loaded
com.apple.netbiosd: Already loaded
com.apple.networkd: Already loaded
com.apple.networkd_privileged: Already loaded
com.apple.NetworkDiagnostics: Already loaded
com.apple.nlcd: Already loaded
com.apple.newsyslog: Already loaded
com.apple.nfsconf: Already loaded
com.apple.nfsd: Already loaded
com.apple.nis.ypbind: Already loaded
com.apple.notifyd: Already loaded
com.apple.ocspd: Already loaded
com.apple.opendirectoryd: Already loaded
com.apple.PCIELaneConfigTool: Already loaded
com.apple.periodic-daily: Already loaded
com.apple.periodic-monthly: Already loaded
com.apple.periodic-weekly: Already loaded
com.apple.pfctl: Already loaded
com.apple.platform.ptmd: Already loaded
com.apple.powerd: Already loaded
com.apple.preferences.timezone.admintool: Already loaded
com.apple.preferences.timezone.auto: Already loaded
com.apple.printtool.daemon: Already loaded
com.apple.racoon: Already loaded
com.apple.RemoteDesktop.PrivilegeProxy: Already loaded
com.apple.RemotePairTool: Already loaded
com.apple.ReportCrash.Root: Already loaded
com.apple.revisiond: Already loaded
com.apple.RFBEventHelper: Already loaded
com.apple.rpcbind: Already loaded
com.apple.rpmuxd: Already loaded
com.apple.sandboxd: Already loaded
com.apple.SCHelper: Already loaded
com.apple.scsid: Already loaded
com.apple.secd: Already loaded
com.apple.security.syspolicy: Already loaded
com.apple.SecurityAgent: Already loaded
com.apple.securityd: Already loaded
com.apple.ServerPerfLog.aslmanager: Already loaded
com.apple.ServerPerfLog: Already loaded
com.apple.shutdown_monitor: Already loaded
com.apple.sleepservicesd: Already loaded
com.apple.smb.preferences: Already loaded
com.apple.softwareupdatecheck.initial: Already loaded
com.apple.softwareupdatecheck.periodic: Already loaded
com.apple.spindump: Already loaded
com.apple.spindump_symbolicator: Already loaded
com.apple.stackshot: Already loaded
com.apple.statd.notify: Already loaded
com.apple.storereceiptinstaller: Already loaded
com.apple.suhelperd: Already loaded
com.apple.syslogd: Already loaded
com.apple.sysmond: Already loaded
com.apple.systemkeychain: Already loaded
com.apple.systempreferences.install: Already loaded
com.apple.systempreferences.writeconfig: Already loaded
com.apple.SystemStarter: Already loaded
com.apple.taskgated-helper: Already loaded
com.apple.taskgated: Already loaded
com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent.system: Already loaded
com.apple.ucupdate.plist: Already loaded
com.apple.uninstalld: Already loaded
com.apple.unmountassistant.sysagent: Already loaded
com.apple.usbmuxd: Already loaded
com.apple.UserEventAgent-System: Already loaded
com.apple.UserNotificationCenter: Already loaded
com.apple.var-db-dslocal-backup: Already loaded
com.apple.vsdbutil: Already loaded
com.apple.warmd: Already loaded
com.apple.webdavfs_load_kext: Already loaded
com.apple.wifid: Already loaded
com.apple.WindowServer: Already loaded
com.apple.xpcd: Already loaded
com.apple.xprotectupdater: Already loaded
com.vix.cron: Already loaded
org.apache.httpd: Already loaded
org.cups.cupsd: Already loaded
org.ntp.ntpd: Already loaded
org.postfix.master: Already loaded
```

Did I started every Damon in that directory? How to restore Daemon startup state from there?

**Edit**: http://pastie.org/private/rwvizio9isyklcsunm4vw - the list of actual running services output from `launchd% list`

**Edit2**: http://pastie.org/7748739 - actual `/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist` file contents.

Comment: They were already running, notice "Already loaded". So the command you used essentially did nothing. There's nothing to restore either, since those things automatically get loaded at startup.

Comment: @l'L'l: Nope; the ones it printed messages for were already loaded, but the ones it *didn't* print messages for weren't (and probably shouldn't be). BTW, Marcel: I take it you ran this as root?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I've restarted it and it looks like it's not starting up any unwanted daemon, but I'm still not sure what the implications, if any.

Comment: I've edited the question with current running services, if someone would compare with another mountain lion in which the mentioned command was not issued. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`launchctl load -w` modifies `/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.501/overrides.plist` and `sudo launchctl load -w` modifies `/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist`.

Try restoring the file that was modified from a backup and restarting. Or you could probably even just delete it. On my mostly untouched 10.8 VM the peruser plist is empty, and the root one looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.ftpd</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>com.apple.mrt</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>com.apple.smbd</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>org.ntp.ntpd</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

com.apple.ftpd doesn't even exist, com.apple.smbd is disabled by default, and org.ntp.ntpd is not disabled by default, so it just disables com.apple.mrt.

Comment: My root file has a lot of keys with Disable false, maybe the command I ran has indeed started every daemon... I'm still stuck as how do I recover to a more or less original state of startup daemons.

Comment: Just try deleting all entries that contain `<key>Disabled</key><false/>` from the overrides.plist. On my account overrides.plist also enables for example com.apple.locate and org.apache.httpd but you can re-enable them manually.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I get home. I just hate that Apple did not followed closer to BSD start/stop daemons mechanisms, or maybe I hate them because I don't have the patience to learn to use launchctl and other utilities.